# 'BackBlazeB2' object has no attribute 'authorization_token'

Tags: storage, b2, backblaze

I'm using b2 B2 Cloud Storage for my django website for year but suddenly I got this error:

```
    Internal Server Error: /post/105/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 106, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 103, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 118, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 246, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 438, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/b2_storage/storage.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.b2 = BackBlazeB2(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/b2_storage/backblaze_b2.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.get_bucket_id_by_name()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/b2_storage/backblaze_b2.py", line 86, in get_bucket_id_by_name
    headers = {'Authorization': self.authorization_token}
AttributeError: 'BackBlazeB2' object has no attribute 'authorization_token'
```